# WCF services by default are restful or soap based?

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, wcf-binding, wcf-data-services

I am new to WCF and just have made a sample service. Please guide me by default WCF services are soap or restful if we not specify anywhere ? I tried to run URL of my services and got this page. I am feeling it is SOAP based. Kindly guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

WCF services by default are SOAP - **unless** you use the `webHttpBinding` which is REST (and this for now is the only RESTful binding). To test your SOAP based services, you cannot just navigate to an URL in your browser - you need to use a SOAP test app, like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) or the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).

*WCF Data Services* and *WCF RIA Services* are based on `webHttpBinding` and thus are REST-based. REST services can be tested by just browsing to the URL - you'll get back XML that can be shown in your browser (or JSON which you can store to a file and look at)

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF services are soap based if you use the project item "WCF Service" in visual studio.